# How To Parse Xml in c# WPF application

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

The UTF don't seem to work on my code. It is saying error in line 125.

```
<feed>

</feed>
```

I have tried specifying what utf am using but dont seem to work

```
  var results = XElement.Load("games.xml")
    .Element("content.items")
    .Element("content.head")
    .Element("content.body")
    .Elements("results")
    .Elements("result");

var query = (from result in results
    let homeTeam = result.Element("home-team")
    let awayTeam = result.Element("away-team")
    let lastScorer = result.Descendants("scorers").Elements("scorer").OrderByDescending(p => (int)p.Attribute("time")).FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
          HomeTeam = homeTeam.Element("team-name").Value,
          AwayTeam = awayTeam.Element("team-name").Value,

          HomeTeamScore = homeTeam.Element("score").Value,
          AwayTeamScore = awayTeam.Element("score").Value,

          LastScorerName = lastScorer != null ? lastScorer.Element("player-name").Value : string.Empty,
          LastScoreTime = lastScorer != null ? (int?)lastScorer.Attribute("time") : null
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your life easier by using [Linq To XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

The following code just work and is more readable than using the low-level XmlReader.

Assuming that the xml is stored in a file named games.xml.

```
    var results = XElement.Load("games.xml")
        .Element("content.items")
        .Element("content.head")
        .Element("content.body")
        .Elements("results")
        .Elements("result");

    var query = (from result in results
        let homeTeam = result.Element("home-team")
        let awayTeam = result.Element("away-team")
        let lastScorer = result.Descendants("scorers").Elements("scorer").OrderByDescending(p => (int)p.Attribute("time")).FirstOrDefault()
        select new
        {
              HomeTeam = homeTeam.Element("team-name").Value,
              AwayTeam = awayTeam.Element("team-name").Value,

              HomeTeamScore = homeTeam.Element("score").Value,
              AwayTeamScore = awayTeam.Element("score").Value,

              LastScorerName = lastScorer != null ? lastScorer.Element("player-name").Value : string.Empty,
              LastScoreTime = lastScorer != null ? (int?)lastScorer.Attribute("time") : null
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: `int.Parse(p.Attribute("time").Value)` can be shortened to `(int)p.Attribute("time")` as `XAttribute` (like `XElement`) implements a conversion to make such conversions a bit easier and shorter.